# What is the best tool for 3D model environment for Android Studio

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, modeling

I'm trying to create to create an app that will house a 3D sphere, with a surface color skin, that the user will be able to manipulate (rotate, zoom in/zoom out, be able to drop pins on coordinates, & other simple tasks like that). I was first considering using OpenGL ES, but I'm currently scared by the following comment taken from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html,

"However, if you want more control of what your application draws on screen, or are venturing into three dimensional graphics, you need to use a different tool."

Is 3D modeling a complete waste of time in OpenGL ES? Am I better off with a different tool?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, page you have linked does not have the quoted text. It´s instead in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) text.
Now, about the text itself: you are taking it out of context and/or misunderstanding it. Here's a full citation:

```
The Android framework provides plenty of 
standard tools for creating attractive, functional 
graphical user interfaces. However, if you want 
more control of what your application draws on 
screen, or are venturing into three dimensional 
graphics, you need to use a different tool. The 
OpenGL ES APIs provided by the Android 
framework offers a set of tools for displaying 
high-end, animated graphics that are limited only 
by your imagination and can also benefit from the 
acceleration of graphics processing units (GPUs) 
provided on many Android devices.
```

Which means that Android provides *standard* tools (Canvas or views), but for more control or 3D graphics you need to use OpenGL ES.

```
Is 3D modeling a complete waste of time in 
OpenGL ES? Am I better off with a different tool?
```

OpenGL ES and the recent Vulkan API are the only tools available for Android which let you do 3D graphics and use GPU more directly.
So, OpenGL ES is what you should use (or Vulkan, if the devices you are targetting have support for it).

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES is just a low-level accelerated rendering API - it will let your application get pretty pixels on to the screen.

All of the higher-level logic (handling rotate, zoom, pins, deciding what to draw, etc) needs to be provided by your application. OpenGL ES provides the tools to help, but it can't provide the logic for you.